# How to control Excel PIVOT tables from cell values with VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I'm trying to refresh my pivot table base on two cell values.  End user will type in value in cell B4 (Region) and value in cell B5 (Department). Pivot table would refresh base on these values.

I found code below, but only allows for referencing 1 cell value. Not sure how to modify it for 2 cell values.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
    'B4 or B5 is touched

    If Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Set the Variables to be used
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim NewCat As String

    'Here you amend to filter your data
    Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Region")
    NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value

    'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
    With pt
        Field.ClearAllFilters
        Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
        pt.RefreshTable
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use the code below to update my Pivot table filters. Hope this is helpful to others.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, 'it only updates when cell'B4
'or B5 is touched

If Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim FieldRegion As PivotField
Dim FieldDept As PivotField
Dim NewRegion As String
Dim NewDept As String

'Amend here to filter your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set FieldRegion = pt.PivotFields("Region")
Set FieldDept = pt.PivotFields("Department")
NewRegion = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value
NewDept = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
FieldRegion.ClearAllFilters
FieldRegion.CurrentPage = NewRegion
FieldDept.ClearAllFilters
FieldDept.CurrentPage = NewDept
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```